# restrictions Not equal criteria default behaviour

Tags: hibernate

I experiment and found that restrictions not equals default nature is ignore case.Please tell me if i m wrong. I m using hibernate 3.x.

For example:-

add(Restrictions.ne("channelCode","JAVA"));

add(Restrictions.ne("channelCode", "JAVA")**.ignorecase()**)

giving me same behaviour for all strings like jAVa, java,JAva etc

Comment: can you add more details that shows `ignorecase()` is not working properly. What data you are having in your tables?

Comment: What DB you are using? I have tested it now on my machine using Oracle DB, I found no issues.

Comment: Like i have three rows in my db with chanelCode values

(id=1  channelCode=java)
(id=2  channelCode=jAVa)
(id=3  channelCode=javac)
but i just getting row with id=3 each time whether i m using ignorecase() or not.

I m using mysql

Comment: Looks like you are missing something, because mysql also supports `lower` function. Can you enable he logging and see what query hibernate is generating with and without `ignorecase`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue, actually mysql search(select)  queries are case insenstive by default.

Thanks for your feed back.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you have done that? `mysql search(select) queries are case insenstive by default.`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  add(Restrictions.ilike("channelCode", "JAVA%"));
```

Comment: i have done like i mentioned above i jus want to confirm is ignorecase is default nature of restrictions.ne() or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `ignorecase()` then hibernate tries to convert the value to lower case and do the comparision like this:

```
lower(this_.channelCode)<>'JAVA'
```

So this should work without any issues.